# How to return class instance from static class?

Tags: c#

I want use a static class that must contains global variables, so I can access to all application controls simply from a variable.
Actually I've this implementation:

```
public static class Globals
{
    public static HeadToHead Head2Head
    {
       get { return Resources.Controls.HeadToHead; }
    }
}
```

in the case above, I want return the instance of `HeadToHead` control, the control look like this:

```
public partial class HeadToHead : UserControl
{
    public static int HomeId = 0;

}
```

my goal is to access to the static variables of this control, like: `Globals.Head2Head.HomeId`

but I get this error on this line: `get { return Resources.Controls.HeadToHead; }`

> HeadToHead is a type which is not valid in the given context

Comment: Any reason why the client wouldn't just use `Resources.Controls.HeadToHead.HomeId` (or some other static property) directly?

Comment: If you really want to return the control, you would have to create an instance of it, something like : `public static HeadToHead Head2Head => new HeadToHead();`

Answer (score 0):

You're returning what looks like a type from a property that seems to be declaring an instance of that type. If you truly want to return that type, there's syntax for that (I don't remember any more, I think in c# it's classname.type). If you want to return an instance, then you need to get that instance from somewhere.

As an aside, static instances of UI controls are a bad idea, and a code smell.

Answer (score 0):

You have to instantiate an instance of the type and return that. As you want a single global instance you could use the static constructor.

```
public static class Globals {

    static Globals(){
       Head2Head = new Resources.Controls.HeadToHead();
    }

    public static HeadToHead Head2Head { get; private set; }
}
```

There are few situations in which you would actually want to do this but common static settings that do not change in the life of the application might be one of them. As `HeadToHead` inherits from `UserControl` that does not really seem to be the case, an instance of a `UserControl` should ideally never be static.

Comment: the error is fixed but when I type this: `Globals.Head2Head.HomeId` I get another error: `cannot be accessed with an instance reference, qualify it with a type name instead` why? thanks

Comment: @stamaaaa - fields declared as `const` on the type should be accessed using the type name and not an instance. If you want to access it on the instance change it from `const` to `readonly` so it can be read but not altered. `public readonly int HomeId = 0;`